# how to cross-compile libncursesw5-dev for arm?

Tags: cross-compiling, ncurses

I have cross-compiled ncurses, that seems to be easy.

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnue --prefix=/home/ncurse
```

then:

```
make
```

Then copied all the contents from prefix directory into the corresponding build-sysroot location， which is the build-sysroot of my cross-compiler.

Then I tried to compile nano:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnue --prefix=/home/nano
```

then

```
make
```

It notices me that it can not find the ncursesw folder.

Then I noticed the resulted include folder and libs of libncursesw5-dev(I got it from Ubuntu by apt-get not but compiled it) are different from ncurses. For example, under /include directory the ncurses will have a folder called ncurses, and libncursesw5-dev will have a folder called ncursesw. 
The files are also different.

I searched for the source of libncursesw5-dev, it re-directed me to the debian package page. where I can only find the source of ncurses.

Is there any way to find the source of libncursesw5-dev? Or did I actually compiled them wrong?
Or what is exactly the relationship between these two?

Comment: How did you cross-compile `ncurses` and how did you install it? How did you cross-compile your code using it? Edit your question to show the actual commands (with four spaces at start of each command line) you used for that

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thnx. I updated it.

Comment: You don't tell enough (how did you install `ncurses`, how did you compile your code using it), or your got the `--prefix=` wrong. It should be some *absolute* directory path and `xxx` is a relative one. Better give the *actual* commands in the question

Comment: And the installing command is also important. Read more about `autoconf`. Notice that `make install` accepts some `DESTDIR=/tmp/destinst` thing (and you can later copy `/tmp/destinst` *appropriately*). So edit your question again to give *all* the *exact* commands you have done. Perhaps start from scratch again.

Comment: At last, you might explore the packaging scripts (for `dpkg`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thnx. I will have a look at the packaging script

Answer (score 0):

You'll better use the *same* prefix for all your [`autoconf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) related cross-compilations. For example

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnue --prefix=$HOME/armstuff
```

For both `ncurses` and `nano`

Perhaps you need to tell all the compilations to look under `$HOME/armstuff/include` for includes and under `$HOME/armstuff/lib` for libraries, e.g. by *adding* `CFLAGS+=-I$HOME/armstuff/include` and `LDFLAGS+=-L$HOME/armstuff/lib` to both `configure` commands.

BTW, you could look at the `Makefile`-s generated by `configure` and you might build with `CFLAGS+=-H` to ask the GCC compiler to show every included file (to understand what exactly is happening at build time).

> Then copied all the contents from prefix directory into the corresponding build-sysroot location， which is the build-sysroot of my cross-compiler.

I don't understand what you did (and build-sysroot is related to configure, and should be passed to it).

I would suggest to install with e.g.

```
make install DESTDIR=/tmp/arminst/
```

then list carefully the content of `/tmp/arminst` and copy it *wisely* with some `cp -va` (but respect your prefix...).

At last, reading about [*Linux From Scratch*](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) should be helpful, and studying the `dpkg` packages too; look also into [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

> Is there any way to find the source of libncursesw5-dev?

It *is* `ncurses`, but you need to understand how the package is built. Maybe learn how to use `apt-build`